# How do I associate multiple form inputs on a ruby back-end

Tags: html, ruby, sinatra

I have an app built on a Ruby back-end (not yet Rails, but using Sinatra at the moment).

In the app, I have a form used to add subscriptions to people. Each subscription can be a trial (in which case, it can have it's own trial start and end dates) and it can also be mailed out in different ways (i.e. we can set a mailing preference for how they want it mailed).

The form I have looks like this:

[image: subscription options]

**What I want to know is how I can associate each input with the subscription? i.e. all inputs on each row must be linked to each other**

Here's my HTML (not sure what else is required, don't really have any back-end for this yet.):

```
<tr>
<th style="vertical-align: top;">Subscriptions</th> 
<td>
    <ul id="subscription-select-list">
        <li class="subscription-select-box">
            <select name="person[subscriptions][]">
                <option value="">Select a subscription</option>
                <% @products.each do |product| %>
                    <optgroup label="<%= product.name %>">
                        <% product.subscriptions.sort_by{|subscription| subscription.name }.each do |subscription| %>
                            <option value="<%= subscription.id %>"><%= subscription.name %></option>
                        <% end %>
                    </optgroup>
                <% end %>
            </select>
            <select name="person[mailing]" id="mailing">
                <option value="">Mailing Preference</option>
                <option value="Cc">Cc</option>
                <option value="BCc">BCc</option>
                <option value="Google Groups">Google Groups</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" id="trial-start" class="datepicker" name="person[trial][start]" placeholder="Trial Start (DD.MM.YYYY)">
            <input type="text" id="trial-end" class="datepicker" name="person[trial][end]" placeholder="Trial End (DD.MM.YYYY)">
            <img src="/img/add_circle.png" alt="Circular add button" class="add-button">
            <img src="/img/remove_circle.png" alt="Circular add button" class="remove-button" style="display: none;">
        </li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

I've set the name of the first select input to `name="person[subscriptions][]"` I was thinking that I could use this to load each row into a hash like:

`{subscription_id: 1, mailing_preference: 'BCc', trial_start: '', trial_end: ''}`

And those would be loaded into an array, like `[{...}, {...}, ...]`, which can be accessed as `params[:person][:subscriptions]`

But I'm not sure how to do it or if that is even the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I found the solution!

As I assumed in my question, it does involve the name attribute. However, it needs slightly more complicated naming - big thanks to [this blog post](http://surrealdetective.github.io/blog/2013/07/01/the-nested-ruby-params-hash-for-complex-html-forms-and-sinatra/) from the Surreal Detective blog for teaching me how it's done!.

If I change the name attributes as follows:

Subscription selector: `person[subscriptions][][id]`
Mailing preference: `person[subscriptions][][mailing]`
Trial Start: `person[subscriptions][][trial][start]`
Trial End: `person[subscriptions][][trial][end]`

Then it gives me a params hash with the subscriptions key like `"subscriptions"=>[{"name"=>"53", "mailing"=>"Cc", "trial"=>{"start"=>"09/17/2017", "end"=>"09/26/2017"}}, {"name"=>"83", "mailing"=>"BCc", "trial"=>{"start"=>"09/05/2017", "end"=>"09/11/2017"}}, ...]`

Which was exactly what I was looking for!

Essentially, `person[:subscriptions]` creates a `subscriptions` key in the `person` hash. The `[]` after that says that the value of the `subscriptions` key should be an array. Adding more attributes within `[]` then creates nested hashes within that array.

i.e. `person[:subscriptions][][:name]` would create a hash like `{"name"=>"53"}` within the `subscriptions` array